# css3 columns in UIWebview

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview

I have a html with lot of text, images, tables and lists that is loaded into UIWebView.
I have applied css style sheet with contents

```
body{ -webkit-column-width: 768px; font-family: "Georgia"; font-size: 12px; height: 1000px }
```

I have enabled the page scrolling horizontally in UIWebView so that I can page the html contents like in an eReader.

```
UIScrollView *scrollview = [webview scrollView];
[scrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

It works but the width of each page ( in iPad it is 768px ), the content from the other pages creeps up incrementally when I start paging to other pages (columns). 
This problem is more visible when I increase the font-size in css to 72px. I need this to work between 12px - 72px range.

How can scroll each (page) column to fit exactly in the screen ?

I am new to css3 and html in general. I really appreciate any help or tips to make this work.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, until I realised that I hadn't set body {margin: 0;}.
Not sure if that will fix your problem, but it worked for me.